# Spring data JPA @EntityGraph for child attributes during JOIN

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to query parent entity (and also mapped entities specified in the EntityGraph) from child entity.

User Entity:

```
public class User{
    private Long userId;
    //other fields
    private Set<UserRoleOrganization> userRoleOrganizations;

    //Setters and getters
}
```

UserToken Entity:

```
public class UserToken{
    private Long userTokenId;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "user_token", length = 100, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String userToken;

}
```

I did like below:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "userRoleOrganizations" })
@Query("Select t.user From UserToken t Where t.userToken = :accessToken")
User findDetailedUserByUserToken(@Param("accessToken") String accessToken);
```

But I got the exception as below:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userRoleOrganizations of: com.dao.domain.security.UserToken
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add the one-to-one relationship from User entity too. in this way you could write query from User side. here is the changes:

### 1. Add another side relation:

- Add UserToken entity relationShip in User

  ```
  public class User{
      @OneToOne(mappedBy='user')
      private UserToken uToken;
      //other fields
      //Setters and getters
  }
  ```

### 2. Rewrite your query:

- You only need your query to be written from user side

  ```
   @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "userRoleOrganizations" })
   @Query("Select t From User t Where t.uToken.userToken = :accessToken")
   User findDetailedUserByUserToken(@Param("accessToken") String accessToken);
  ```

Comment: Thanks for you response. If I add OneToOne then every time it will fetch by default as its EAGER Fetch. I tried to use OneToOne Fetch type as LAZY but its not working. I had checked in google and SO already but came to know that LAZY fetch wont work with OneToOne.